# Cannot delete existing PayPal Sandbox account

Tags: sandbox

Why can't I delete the accounts I have in the PayPal Sandbox? I checkmark the chosen accounts, go down to "delete" and it saystry again (????), feedback appreciated

Comment: Please provide some more information, i have just tried deleting the account and it allow me, Select a/c - ask for confirmation - Successfully Deleted accounts

Comment: I have this problem now. I have several dozen test accounts. I can delete all, but one will not allow deletion. If I find an answer I will post.